# Angular have different api endpoints for each module

Tags: angular

in my Angular application I use an injection token for configuring my backends API urls

```
export ENDPOINT = new InjectionToken<string>('ENDPOINT');
```

and in the corresponding `app.module` I used this

```
providers: [
{
  provide: ENDPOINT,
  useValue: 'https://backend-1',
}
```

this worked really fine.
Now I have the case that I have different modules, which should itself have different endpoints. I am currently struggeling how to configure this `ENDPOINT` to support multiple endpoints for the different modules.
As a constraint, I dont want to create an extra `ENDPOINT` for each module. the existing one should be reused

Desired way:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: ENDPOINT,
    useValue: [
      {endpoint: 'https://1', module: AppModule },
      {endpoint: 'https://2', moduel: BModule }
    ]
  }
```

Is this somehow possible ?

Answer (score 0):

> As a constraint, I dont want to create an extra ENDPOINT for each module. the existing one should be reused

I assume with extra `ENDPOINT` you mean something like `ENDPOINT1` and `ENDPOINT2`. My suggestion is to use the multiple option.

```
providers: [
  { provide: ENDPOINT, useValue: 'https://backend-1', multi: true },
  { provide: ENDPOINT, useValue: 'https://backend-2', multi: true }
```

With this option you need to change your injected value to an array

```
constructor(@Inject(ENDPOINT) endpoints: string[]) {}
```

Comment: this definetly goes into the right direction. I just wonder how a Module should then decide which one to use

Comment: You cannot provide a token or a service for a module from another module. Each module need to define the provider for itself (or import it via a module import). The suggested way would provide several endpoints to a single module. I thought you mean that.

Comment: Maybe you want something like a proxy? https://morioh.com/p/07bddb33e3ab